# How to return an html file using Spring MVC controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm working on a website using both WaveMaker and Springsource MVC.

The entry generated by WaveMaker is named 'index.html'. I import all browser-side code into the /view directroy of an MVC project. And try to configure ContextLoadListener to map it into an uri. Using:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/index", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String testIndex() {

    return "index.html";
}
```

Then I got the following error testing it:

```
SEVERE: PWC6117: File "C:\glassfish3\glassfish\domains\domain1\eclipseApps\TribblesDashboard\WEB-INF\views\index.html.jsp" not found
```

How do I fix it?

Comment: See http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#mvc-viewresolver. But the easiest solution is to rename the index.html file to index.jsp.

Comment: Looks like your viewResolver isn't configured correctly.  Do you have one defined?

Comment: The default viewResolver behaviour is to automatically looks for the returned view name with ".jsp" on the end. So rename "index.html" to "index.jsp" and then return just "index"

Answer (score 2):

This can be due to two reasons.

1. The declaration of view resolver in application context. This should be some thing like this:

```xml
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/WEB-INF/jsp/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

This indicates that the views should be placed in the `WEB-INF/jsp` folders.

2. The second is to check the Dispatcher Servlet configuration in the `web.xml`.

```xml
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>DispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>DispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Check if the mappings are OK.

Comment: Thank you so much! These are exactly what I need.
On the seccond part. My servlet-mapping pattern was set to:
 <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>

Comment: Can you please mark the answer as the correct one so that the others who face the same problem will be benefited. Thanks!

Comment: Whoops: there is still a problem, but now the error information has become:

INFO: WARN : org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/tribblesdashboard/WEB-INF/views/index.html] in DispatcherServlet with name 'appServlet'

And as before, returns a 404 error. Seems like I missed something

Comment: Interesting, I have manually added the required mapping:
 @RequestMapping(value = "/tribblesdashboard/WEB-INF/views/home.html", method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public String ddefault(Locale locale) {
  return "/tribblesdashboard/WEB-INF/views/home.html";
 }
But still got the same result

Comment: If the above solution does not work then look for the location of the html is it really present in `WEB-INF/jsp folder` or the `WEB-INF/views` folder. Change the mapping of the InternalResourceViewResolver in the application context.       `<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
   <property name="prefix">
     <value>--Change this ---/WEB-INF/jsp/</value>
   </property>
   <property name="suffix">
     <value>.jsp</value>
   </property>
</bean>`